# Create OK/Cancel dialog

Tags: python, enthought, enaml

It should be so simple, but I have not been able to figure out how to do a simple OK/cancel confirmation dialog in enaml.  Could someone please enlighten me?  I am using an ETS toolkit of Qt4 with pyside api, python 2.7, and enaml 0.6.8.

My application consists of a MainWindow and is launched like the following:

```
from enaml.stdlib.sessions import simple_session
from enaml.qt.qt_application import QtApplication

...

session = simple_session('myApp',...)

app = QtApplication([session])
app.start_session('myApp')
app.start()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Does seem like there should be a built-in widget. Nevertheless, based on the FileDialog example that ships with enaml, here's something that works and the pattern is readily extensible.

```
from enaml.layout.api import vbox, align
from enaml.widgets.api import Window, Container, Label, PushButton


enamldef Main(Window): main_win:

    title = 'Main'
    attr dlg_result : str = 'waiting'

    Container:
        constraints = [
            vbox(pb, lbl),
            align('h_center', lbl, pb),
        ]

        Label: lbl:
            align = 'center'
            text << main_win.dlg_result

        PushButton: pb:
            text = 'Dialog'
            clicked ::
                session.add_window( TheDialog(listener=main_win,result='dlg_result') )

enamldef TheDialog(Window): dlg_win:
    title = 'Dialog'
    modality = 'application_modal' # one of ['non_modal', 'window_modal', 'application_modal']
    attr listener
    attr result

    Container:
        constraints = []

        PushButton: ok_btn:
            text = 'Okay'
            clicked ::
                setattr(listener, result, 'Okay')
                dlg_win.close()

        PushButton: cancel_btn:
            text = 'Cancel'
            clicked ::
                setattr(listener, result, 'Cancel')
                dlg_win.close()
```